# Fast search in a derived column in a view

Tags: postgresql, search, view

I have a view that uses a format string for a certain column:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS 
    SELECT FORMAT('%s-%s-%s-%s', col1, col2, col3, col4) data
    FROM table;
```

This works fine, but I want to search on that column quite some time. And, when there are many rows in the table, it takes a while. The format string is in fact stored in another table and may be changed by the user, so I cannot just put the formatted string in the table and index that.

What would be a good solution to make the queries faster?

Comment: Functional indexes? Materialized view?

Comment: Functional indexes indeed make it faster.

Comment: Materialized view need refreshing, which implies more work on other parts of the system.